# Unlinking checkboxes

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have 3 checkboxes. When I check one, others get checked too. How to unlink them?

```
//Validating Permition

if(shUserForm.getRange("C14").getValue() == "0"){

ui.alert("Blank is Not Available! Choose your Permition");

return false;

} else if(shUserForm.getRange("C17").getValue() == "0"){

ui.alert("Blank is Not Available! Choose your Permition");

return false;

} else if(shUserForm.getRange("C24").getValue() == "0"){

ui.alert("Blank is Not Available! Choose your Permition");

return false;

}

}

if (shUserForm.getRange("C14").getValue() == "1") {
         datasheet.getRange(blankRow,8).setValue('=CHAR(10004)').getValue(); // Confirm of Late
         datasheet.getRange(blankRow,8).setBackground('#E06666');}

         if (shUserForm.getRange("C17").getValue() == "1") {
         datasheet.getRange(blankRow,9).setValue('=CHAR(10004)').getValue(); // Confirm of Nofinger
         datasheet.getRange(blankRow,9).setBackground('#E06666');}

         if (shUserForm.getRange("C24").getValue() == "1") {
         datasheet.getRange(blankRow,10).setValue('=CHAR(10004)').getValue(); // Confirm of Offwork
         datasheet.getRange(blankRow,10).setBackground('#E06666');}
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The question title should be a summary of the question body, by the other hand the code isn't complete, and a brief description of how it works is missing. Please bear in mind that question on this site should be specific. Ref. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

See if [mutuallyExclusiveCheckboxes_()](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/33103575?msgid=34010933) works for you.

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).